# When can an AggregateException contain more than 1 inner exception?

Tags: .net, exception, task-parallel-library

I have a question regarding the .NET Task Parallel Library's error handling. In which cases will an `AggregateException` hold more than 1 inner exception? I know this can happen for ex. when calling `Task.WaitAll(anArrayOfTasks)`, and 2 or more tasks are throwing an exception, but are there any other cases (i.e., can it be possible that, if only waiting for 1 task to finish, you get more than 1 inner exceptions)?

Comment: Not related to Parallel Library. Suppose you have a method to delete a list of files, but some are locked. You can use an `AggregateException` to rethrow for the locked files and continue to delete the rest of the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A task can raise an aggregate exception which inherently can contain multiple inner exceptions. This means that you should always consider an aggregate exception with multiple inner exceptions when working with tasks. Even if you're not using Task.WaitAll, the task you're waiting on might internally wait for multiple subtasks. Alternatively, the task your waiting on might return multiple exceptions. You simply can't know as a caller.

Comment: I agree that in the general case, you should assume that you might get a list of exceptions and design your error handling as such, I just want to know if handling a single async task which does not depend on other async tasks will ever create a situation in which more than 1 exception is being passed.

Comment: Might, just might. It's not very likely though. IF the inner task waits for mulitple child tasks. A new AggregateException will be created containing 1 AggregateException containing multiple (possibly aggregate!) inner exceptions. Therefore its always a good practice to call the Flatten method over the AggregateException in order to get all exceptions and handle them as a collection

Comment: How would you pass the errors to the UI in this case? Normally, if performing an operation, you can have two outcomes, either success, or an error. Designing an UI to implicitly handle error lists would seem confusing in my oppinion, and having two cases (one for one error and one for multiple errors) seems to overcomplicate things. I was thinking of always handling at most 1 exception in the UI, and logging all exceptions (and presenting a message to the user to check the error log for ex).

Comment: Thats a valid question. Going Async means that instead of having the luxury of havign linear code where if one branch fails, you can precisely act , you have multiple branches of code that execute at the same time where each one of them can end up in a unsuspected state (exception) and you have to recover from all of them. Exception handling is not as simple as showing a message box. What if your download operation fails in the middle. Is the socket closed? What if 2 async download operations fail? I would suggest you rethink your design based on async principles

Comment: I presented an oversimplified version of what I'm trying to achieve, but still, I will probably treat exceptions on a per-case basis, as exception handling in async scenarios is too complicated to find a silver bullet for it.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you have a “parent” task and one or more “child” tasks that are attached to the parent. What that means is that the parent task will finish only when all of its child tasks finish and the exceptions from child tasks are also propagated to the parent task.

Take, for example, the following code:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => { throw new Exception("inner"); },
            TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        throw new Exception("outer");
    });
```

If you `Wait()` on that task, it thows an `AggregateException`, that looks like this:

- `AggregateException`

  - `Exception`: outer
  - `AggregateException`

    - `Exception`: inner

If you don't like that it can contain `AggregateException`s inside `AggregateException`s, you can use [the `Flatten()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.flatten.aspx). There's also another method that can be used for processing of `AggregateException`s: [`Handle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.handle.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1 for mentioning the Handle() method, I didn't know about that.